# How can I change a matrix param value without affecting other parts of the route?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to build a component which reads and writes a matrix parameter on an arbitrary page. It doesn't know anything about the page it's on.

I can depend on `ActivatedRoute` to get the parameter *for the current route*, but when I want to *change* the parameter, I can't figure out how to build a URL tree / commands that won't annihilate parent or child params. I *think* I want to call some flavor of `router.navigate`.

Concretely, given that:

- the current URL is `/foo/qux/bar;option=A/baz;tab=all` (see sample route structure below).
- I want to change "option" to B.
- I want the final URL to be `/foo/qux/bar;option=B/baz;tab=all`

I cannot figure out a solution that simultaneously

- preserves path and matrix params from the parent
- preserves child route and params
- doesn't promote parent path params to matrix params
- doesn't discard other matrix params on the current route.
- doesn't depend on too much string manipulation (there can be multiple params named "option" in the URL).

Example route structure:

```js
[
  {
    path: 'foo/:id',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bar',
        component: PageWithMyComponentOnIt,
        children: [
          {path: 'baz'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```